# Como voltar para a página anterior com botão físico do smartphone - Ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, mobile

Como permito que o botão físico **voltar** do celular realize uma determinada função no **Ionic 3**? (No caso, uma função que faz o aplicativo abrir a página inicial)

Comment: Você quer alterar a função padrão do botão de voltar?

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Na verdade, a única função que ele exerce no meu app (o botão **físico**) é de fechar o app em qualquer página que esteja, gostaria que ele exercesse a função mais "comum" dele que é voltar a página anterior do app.

Comment: Estranho isso.. talvez seja a maneira de navegação que você está utilizando, pois normalmente a funcionalidade é justamente esta, remover a view atual e ir pra anterior.. de uma lida na documentação do Ionic sobre o serviço [Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction)

Comment: Então, eu estou utilizando a Native Transitions, talvez seja por isso. Enfim, há algum modo de fazer o botão físico ter utilidade que eu desejo mesmo com a maneira de navegação diferente da default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Teiji, você pode utilizar o serviço Platform, com ele você pode registrar a ação do botão com uma função, por exemplo:

```
export class AnyPage{

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
              private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    });
  }
}
```

A partir desse momento, sempre que você apertar o botão físico do celular, ele executará o `this.navCtrl.pop()`, mas não sei se usando o Native Transitions a ação do NavController será útil.